# Load Flash plugin after it's been installed on Android

Tags: android

My android app is my website loaded into a `WebView`. Flash is required to view the videos on my website, so I use Javascript to put up a download prompt when Flash is not detected:

[image: get flash]

When my site is viewed through the stock Browser app, all the user has to do is refresh the page to instantiate Flash. But this doesn't work on my `WebView` app. No matter how many times I reload or reset the plugin state, Flash does not instantiate.

```
protected void onRestart() {
   super.onRestart();
   this.webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
   this.webView.reload();
}
```

The user is forced to kill the app and restart it for Flash to instantiate. This is a poor user experience, as regular users don't understand memory management. For the best experience, I would like to programatically instantiate Flash for the user after it's been installed. How would I do this?

Comment: Hey, I'm facing the same issue... Have u found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

When you start your WebView you should get the WebSettings object and setup all the attributes about your WebView. From there you can enable/disable many things. For your case, if you want to enable plug-ins just do this:

Get the settings from you WebView...
`WebView webView = new WebView(this);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();`

And enable it...
`webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);`

Comment: Let me look into this tomorrow, I had this problem before and my simple web browser that I made seems to work just fine with all Flash content and I don't remember it being any more complicated than that.